# How can i get all the sub-children?

Tags: excel, loops, parent-child, powerquery, recursive-query

[source link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nbF7-ZBZNMCmHdzSqqfBdHCPNqdWfKGa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104317018191542815438&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image]

Hello guys, so i have a function ("flecheD"),

```
(ColChild,ColParent,ParentActuel,source)=>
                    let
                    mylist=Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(source,each Record.Field(_,ColParent)=ParentActuel),ColChild),
                    resultat=Text.Combine(mylist)
                    in
                   
                   Text.Trim(
                    if resultat ="" then ""  else @ resultat &"|" & @ flecheD(ColChild,ColParent,resultat,source),"|")
```

which loops through 2 columns (Parent,Child) to get all children of the main parent (output->Children column). The problem is that when the function is confronted with several children, the resultat variable no longer has a single letter/child but several, which blocks the function from looking for the other sub-children.

In order to solve this,  I tried to create a custom function "SubChilldren" with List.Generate()

```
(children as text, ColChild,ColParent,source)=>
let 
i = 1,
length = Text.Length(children),

subchildren =  List.Generate( ()=>@flecheD(ColChild,ColParent,Text.At(children,i-1),source),   i<=length, i+1  )
in 
Text.Combine(subchildren)
```

which when coupled with my initial function

```
(ColChild,ColParent,ParentActuel,source)=>
                    let
                    mylist=Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(source,each Record.Field(_,ColParent)=ParentActuel),ColChild),
                    resultat=Text.Combine(mylist)
                    in
                   
                   Text.Trim(
                    if resultat ="" then ""  else if Text.Length(resultat) = 1 then  @ resultat &"|" & @ flecheD(ColChild,ColParent,resultat,source)
                    else     @resultat &"|"& SubChildren(resultat,ColChild,ColParent,source),"|")
```

should normally get the sub-children  of each children. However, it doesnt work . Could you please help me . Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was a fun way, but you could write a recursive function as well. I have it hard coded to 4 levels of children deep

(not sure how in your source data D child can have two parents, c and J, but whatever)

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
   
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Parent"}, {{"data", each List.RemoveNulls(_[Child]), type list}}),
Parent_List = List.Buffer(#"Grouped Rows"[Parent] ),
Child_List = List.Buffer(#"Grouped Rows"[data] ),

Process =  (n as list) as list =>
   let children = List.Transform(List.Transform(n, each  Text.ToList(_)), each Text.Combine( List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(_, each try Child_List{List.PositionOf( Parent_List, _ )} otherwise null))))) in children,

Level1=Process(Source[Parent]),
Level2=Process(Level1),
Level3=Process(Level2),
Level4=Process(Level3),
Final=List.Transform(List.Positions(Level1),each Level1{_}&"|"&Level2{_}&"|"&Level3{_}&"|"&Level4{_}&"|"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Table.FromList(Final),"||","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(#"Replaced Value"),
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Children"})
in custom2
```

[image]

edited to be generic so it can take text as well as numerical inputs

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Parent", type text}, {"Child", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Parent"}, {{"data", each List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(_[Child]), each Text.From(_)), type list}}),
Parent_List = List.Buffer(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[Parent], each Text.From(_))),
Child_List = List.Buffer(#"Grouped Rows"[data]),
Process =  (n as list) as list =>let children = List.Transform(List.Transform(n, each Text.Split(_,",") ) , each try Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(_, each try Child_List{List.PositionOf( Parent_List, _ )} otherwise ""))),"," ) otherwise "") in children,
Level1=Process(#"Changed Type"[Parent]),
Level2=Process(Level1),
Level3=Process(Level2),
Level4=Process(Level3),
Final=List.Transform(List.Positions(Level1),each Level1{_}&"|"&Level2{_}&"|"&Level3{_}&"|"&Level4{_}&"|"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Table.FromColumns({Final}),"||","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & Table.ToColumns(#"Replaced Value"),
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & {"Children"})
in custom2
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it works great. A different way indeed but thank you. I guess your method could also be used in reverse to find the primary parent, am I wrong?

Comment: This would not work for primary parent. And in your case, you seem to have multiple primary parents (eg child D). What you'd want for that is traversing up the tree. I have a function for that if you need it and start another question

Comment: Hi, i get an  error when i tried  to replace the letters with digits, like 11 instead of A, 22 instead of B. I tried to change the format to Text but i'm still blocked, could you please help me out. And could you show  me how to get the children in a list instead of text type, for exemple for parent A: children = {B,J,C,U,D,I}  Thanks

Comment: edited to handle numbers. your other question is another question